# Как запустить backend express и react-server с одной команды?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Приветствую, использую `express` для backend.

`package.json` имеет скрипт для запуска сервера (port 3001):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require should --recursive tests"
  },
```

Так же использую `create-react-app` для frontend (port 3000), ставил его в `~/project-name/client` он имеет команды для запуска:

```
npm start - Starts the development server.

npm run build - Bundles the app into static files for production.

npm test - Starts the test runner.
```

У него в `~/project-name/client/package.json` добавил:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

Если я из под `~/project-name/` запущу `node start`, то запустится `express`.
Как мне запускать их оба одной командой?